# adding non-database steps in rails transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, transactions

I'm currently working on a Rails application, and I have a situation where I'm using a transaction like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  db_step
  non_db_step
  db_step
end
```

I'm wondering if it's better to remove the non-database step from the transaction, or if it doesn't make a significant difference. I'd appreciate an explanation of how Rails handles these cases.

Assuming that the order of execution doesn't affect the outcome, and there are no specific actions to be taken if the transaction fails, I'm primarily concerned with performance. Is it necessary to make an effort to remove non-database steps from the transaction, or does it not significantly impact performance?

Comment: It really depends what those steps are doing. Are they order dependent? What should happen if the db transaction fails?

Comment: Rails cannot "undo" the non-database step for you. If the first `db_step` fails and raises an exception, `non_db_step` will be skipped. However, if the second `db_step` fails, `non_db_step` will already have been executed. This might introduce unwanted side effects.

Comment: Assuming that the order of execution doesn't affect the outcome, and there are no specific actions to be taken if the transaction fails, I'm primarily concerned with performance. Is it necessary to make an effort to remove non-database steps from the transaction, or does it not significantly impact performance?

Comment: It might impact overall performance if the non-database part takes a significant amount of time because certain rows might be locked longer than needed. But that depends on what you are doing.

Comment: what i am actually doing that there is preprocessing between each db call inside each function
i.e


transaction begin
fun1
fun2
fun3
end


i am trying to extract all pre-processing before the transaction by split each function into 2 functions
to be as the following


pre1
pre2
pre3
transaction begin
fun1
fun2
fun3
end


and here fun1 contains as least as possible of non-db related processing

Comment: Although it's generally a good idea to keep transactions small and short, you might want to measure the time / impact of those preprocessing steps before restructuring your whole code. (→ [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize))